# Scripts not working in React, NextJS project unless I specifically refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I had to refactor a large codebase built on pure HTML, CSS, and javascript into a ReactJS and NextJS application. The codebase had a whole lot of links and scripts whereby some scripts applied for all pages while some applied for only specific pages.

In the set-up I did, I created a Meta.js file where I kept all links and scripts and also created a Layout.js file which held the Meta.js as well a common navbar and sidebar layout which was applied to all pages.

The issue I am facing presently now is that some scripts/functionality do not work unless the page is refreshed. For instance, I enter the application from the homepage which is the index.js file, and then navigate to the settings page, which is a settings.js file.

The settings.js page has some tab that uses some script in it but will not work unless I reload the page. What can be the issue with this and how can I fix this.

Here are some of the important files listed below:

Meta.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Script from 'next/script'

const Meta = ({title, keywords, description}) => {
  return (
    <>
    <Head>
      <meta charSet="utf-8" />
      <meta content="Webflow" name="generator" />
    </Head>
    <Script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"></Script>
    <Script src='/CustomScript.js'></Script>
    <Script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js' strategy='beforeInteractive' crossOrigin="anonymous"></Script>
    <Script src='/webflow.js'></Script>
    <Script src='https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/js/datepicker.js'></Script>
    <Script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr'></Script>
    <Script src='https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js' strategy='beforeInteractive'></Script>
    </>
  )
}

export default Meta
```

Layout.js

```
import Nav from "./Nav";
import Meta from "./Meta";

const Layout = ({children}) => {
  return ( 
    <>
    <Meta />
    <Nav/>
    <div className="body">
      <main>
        {children}
      </main>
    </div>
    </>
   );
}
 
export default Layout;
```

_app.js

```
// styles
import '../styles/normalize.css'
import '../styles/webflow.css'
import '../styles/listwise.webflow.css'
import '../styles/styles.css'
// website constant layout
import Layout from '../components/Layout'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Nav.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app-nav-layout">
            <Link href="#"><Image src="/listwise-logo-black-nospace.svg" width={130} height={130} alt="" className="left-navbar-logo" /></Link>
          </div>
          <nav role="navigation" className="left-navbar-menu w-nav-menu">
                  <Link href="/dashboard/listings/addListing">Create new listing</Link>
                <Link href="/">Dashboard<br/></Link>
                <Link href="/dashboard/listings/allListings"><a className="left-navbar-link w-nav-link"><span className="material-icons-round md-18 mr-8">list_alt</span> Listings<br/></a></Link>
                <Link href="/dashboard/settings/settings">Account settings</Link>
                <Link href="/dashboard/listings/myListwise">My Listwise</Link>
          </nav>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

settings.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Head from "next/head"
import Script from "next/script"

const settings = () => {

  return (
<>
<Head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.min.css" />
    <Script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-file-encode/dist/filepond-plugin-file-encode.min.js"></Script>
    <Script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.min.js"></Script>
  </Head>

<div className="app-main-layout-container">
                  <div className="tabs-menu w-tab-menu">
                    <a data-w-tab="Personal" className="tab-link w-inline-block w-tab-link w--current">
                      <div className="material-icons-round md-24 icon-acc-settings">person</div>
                      <div className="tab-text">Personal profile</div>
                    </a>
                    <a data-w-tab="Business" className="tab-link w-inline-block w-tab-link">
                      <div className="material-icons-round md-24 icon-acc-settings">store</div>
                      <div className="tab-text">Business profile</div>
                    </a>
                    <a data-w-tab="Social" className="tab-link w-inline-block w-tab-link">
                      <div className="material-icons-round md-24 icon-acc-settings">share</div>
                      <div className="tab-text">Social links</div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div className="tabs-content w-tab-content">
                    <div data-w-tab="Personal" className="w-tab-pane w--tab-active">
                      <div className="w-form">
                        <form id="wf-form-profile" name="wf-form-profile" data-name="profile" method="get">
                          <div className="form-group"><label htmlFor="name-4" className="label">Upload profile photo</label>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div data-w-tab="Business" className="w-tab-pane">
                      <div className="w-form">
                        <form id="wf-form-profile" name="wf-form-profile" data-name="profile" method="get">
                          <div className="form-group"><label htmlFor="name-4" className="label">Business name</label>
                            <div className="hint marginb--20px">This is usually the name you work under</div><input type="text" className="input w-input" maxLength="256" name="Business-Name" data-name="Business Name" placeholder="Enter business name" id="business-name" required="" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div data-w-tab="Social" className="w-tab-pane">
                      <div className="w-form">
                        <form id="wf-form-profile" name="wf-form-profile" data-name="profile" method="get">
                          <div className="form-group"><label htmlFor="instagram-link" className="label">Instagram profile link</label><input type="text" className="input w-input" maxLength="256" name="Instagram-Link" data-name="Instagram Link" placeholder="www.instagram.com/myname" id="instagram-link" /></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</>
  )
}

export default settings
```

Also, I will like to ask how best to render those scripts that only work for specific pages, should I add the to the Meta.js file which gets loaded on the initial rendering of the application, or creates a separate file and add it to the page that needs it when the page is navigated to.

Comment: You should read about routing https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, thank you. I do know about routes and have also gone through the reference you shared but can't figure out how that is related to the current issue I am facing.

Comment: Hi, i think you can try adding those script on respective components head section by using Script tag. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script . I hope this will help :)

Answer (score 3):

The Nextjs Script component can take a `strategy` prop. It has a default value of `afterInteractive` which means the script will first load the main javascript that's necessary for the page to become interactive **before** the script you've linked in the `Script` tag.

If you need any script to load early because some functionality of your page relies on it you'd want to set the strategy prop to `beforeInteractive` like so:

```
<Script src=" ... " strategy="beforeInteractive" />
```

More information on [Next docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#strategy)

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this issue but for the time being i just fixed this issue by importing all script code into useEffect here i am removing all events before my script code in useEffect

```
 useEffect(() => {
      $(document).ready(function () {
      var allElems = $('body').find('*');
      allElems.each(function () {
      var elm = this, //javascript DOM object
      $elm = $(this) //jquery object for element.
      $elm.off();
      // your script code here
   });
 });
```